# call function from code behind in javascript without postback

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, postback

I have a list of customers that the user can choose from. When they select a customer, I need to load the contacts of that customer. I needed to call the function from JavaScript so I added a button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSample" runat="server" style="float:right;display:none" OnClick="btnSample_Click" />
```

and that button then gets triggered from my JavaScript function:

```
function OnGetCustomer(result){
                document.getElementById('lblCustID').innerHTML = result.ID;
                document.getElementById('lblCustName').innerHTML = result.Name; 
                document.getElementById("btnSample").click();
}
```

Code behind to load the contacts:

```
protected void btnSample_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RateSheet r = new RateSheet(ID, Company.Current.CompanyID);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblCustID.Text))
        {
            Customer c = new Customer(int.Parse(lblCustID.Text));

            bool e2 = false;
            foreach (Customer.CustomerContact cc in c.Contacts)
            {
                HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
                CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
                cb.ID = "cbCustContact_" + cc.ID;
                cb.Checked = true;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cc.Email))
                {
                    cb.Text = cc.Email;
                    cb.TextAlign = TextAlign.Right;
                    li.Controls.Add(cb);
                    ulCustContacts.Controls.Add(li);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I need the value from `lblCustID` to find the customer's contacts. The problem is the button causes postback and I lose the customer I selected so `lblCustID` always comes back as zero. How do I stop postback so I don't lose any values?

Comment: Add the customerid to hiddenfield so that it will be posted to the server when the postback happens and you can read it on the server side.

Comment: Sounds like you need an ajax request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `lblCustID` a label or an input? The only* controls in which changes are preserved in postback are inputs. You can use `<asp:HiddenField />` or any `<input runat="server" ... />` to send information for the code behind to work with.

*Along with other controls such as dropdownlists etc

Comment: `lblCustID` is a label. So changing that to a HiddenField worked. But I am still losing my other labels like `lblCustName` because of the postback. Changing it to `<input runat="server" type="text" id="lblCustName" />` makes it a textbox. Is there a way to set it to label so it is still preserved in postback?

Comment: Are you changing those labels via javascript too? Either way, labels are not saved in the ASP viewstate (a hidden field asp uses to repopulate controls afterpostback). The way to do that would be to pair up each lable with a hidden control, then on page load, change the label text to the value in the hidden control

Comment: what do you mean changing the labels?

Comment: Changing the label value with JS, it appears that you are. (I was too slow to edit my comment: The hidden field would mirror the labels text (via JS) and after postback, on page load you could change the label text to the value in the hidden field (again via JS))

Answer (score 1):

You can use asynchronous call to achieve that:

Set **AutoPostback="false"** to prevent the button to cause postback onclick

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSample" runat="server" style="float:right" AutoPostback="false" />
```

Or just add a raw HTML button (ATTENTION: add a **type="button"** or this will cause a postback):

```
<button id="btnSample" type="button">Click</button>
```

Then add an event listener to this button and execute the ajax call:

```
$(document).on('click', '[id$=btnSample]', function() {
   ajax({
      url: 'path/to/handler',
      method: 'POST',
      data: { key: 'value', ... },
      success: function(data) {
         OnGetCustomer(data);
      },
      error: function() {
         console.log('Error on ajax call!');
      }
   });
});
```

**NOTE**: You have to move your cobebehind code into a generic handler to handle the ajax call and return the result